# why my angularjs filter not working?

Tags: angularjs

I use this filter
I want filter the number 2 to 4 but this filter number 0 to 4

```
   <tr class="table-row" ng-repeat="advert in adverts| orderBy:sortByCol.key| limitTo:4:20">
```

this is the part im using  limitTo:4:20

please help me

Comment: Read the documentation on [`limitTo`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo)—it imposes a length limit, not a restriction on the values permitted for display (you probably want [`filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) instead).

Comment: but how i can start by the order two exist any way?

Comment: i see this expression is imitTo : limit : begin   what mean begin ?

Comment: i see this works in version 1.4 of angularjs

Comment: The documentation clearly states that `begin` is an offset index from which to begin the limiting the number of items in the `ng-repeat` collection to display. Play around with it yourself here—http://plnkr.co/edit/9tSh5iZw3BCcBG6aDpSD?p=preview

Comment: this works for me very thankyou